# how to use Junit5 @TempDir with Kotlin ? ("JvmField can only be applied to final property" compile error)

Tags: kotlin, junit5, tempdir

I'm trying (without any luck so far) to use Junit5 @Tempdir annotation with Kotlin.
Following a previous stackoverflow post ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68202376/how-to-use-junit-5s-tempdir-with-kotlin)), I've tried the code below:

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyClass {

    @TempDir
    @JvmField
    var tempFolder: File? = null
    
    @Test
    fun mytest() {
        assert(true);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately I get the following error at compilation: "JvmField can only be applied to final property"...
Any idea ?
Thanks a lot in advance for your expertise and your time.
Best Regards

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either, but I also couldn't try the extension... So I'm curious what happens when you remove the `@ExtendWith` annotation?

Comment: @Abby : thanks a lot for your feedback ! The problem wasn't ExtendWith annotation but rather with SpringBootTest annotation (but you pointed me into the right direction) . I modified my code example accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other people still looking for an answer, below code works around above-mentionned issue:

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyClass {

    @Test
    fun mytest() {
        assert(true);
    }
    
    companion object {
        @TempDir
        lateinit var tempFolder: File
    }
}
```